# INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER error in Inbound Shipment Amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

We are using CreateInboundShipment API to create inbound shipment in amazon, but some time we are getting INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER error from amazon.

> Invalid Items found - ShipmentId [#######] MerchantCustomerId
>   [#########] InvalidItems[ (skuType=MSKU, sku=####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=#####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=#####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=#####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=#####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=#####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER), (skuType=MSKU, sku=#####,
>   reason=INCOMPATIBLE_PREPOWNER)]

Is there any issue in Amazon Products or what is PREPOWNER in amazon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the [CreateInboundShipment](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_CreateInboundShipment.html) call you are sending `InboundShipmentItems` which in turn has an element [PrepDetails](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_Datatypes.html#PrepDetails) which includes a `PrepOwner`. This field - according to the documentation - has to be either "AMAZON" or "SELLER" with "SELLER" being the default.